# How to make my app zoom into my location using MapKit

Tags: xcode, location, mapkit, apple-maps

I have tried to make an app like uber in which the app should zoom into your location and display a circle showing your location. It is displaying the map But it is not showing the exact location with the blue dot...

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Errors" + error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Thank you For your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the Interface builder, select the `mapView` and in the Attributes Inspector, check the box for "Show user's location" and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

For location manager to work one of the requisites is to have the in info.plist the tag 'NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription' or 'NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription'. These are just the things that get said when the app asks you for permission to use it.